# Php/MySql array search with ã, š, é, ë, ú, ü, í, ž

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

Hi everybody
If someone search for term "zali se mami" in mySql database, what is the best way to make all possible replacements with appropriate signs (for example e => ë, e => é, a => ã, u => ü, u => ú...) so he/she could get all possible results like:
"žali se mami"
"žali se màmi"
"žàli se mami"
"žàli së mami"

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `utf8_general_ci` collation on the column. You can read more about the effects of the collation at these two pages in the MySQL manual:

[Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) and [Examples of the Effect of Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html)