# Codeigniter like chars with diacritic?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, chars

Is possible to "learn" codeigniget to recognize chars like ľščťžýáíé or ĽŠČŤŽÝÁÍÉ ? Cause I want not to have search sensitive to those chars. For example if I have in my table row "Šilíoá" and I search for silioa nothing will be foung. But if I am searching for silioa it will be found. So I think that problem is in Š is it possible for example to learn codeigniter to recognize Š? Or Ž etc.?
Here is my query:

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`knihy`) 
                  WHERE `stav` = 1 
                  AND (Autor1 LIKE '$vyraz' 
                  OR Autor2 LIKE '$vyraz' 
                  OR Autor3 LIKE '$vyraz' 
                  OR Autor4 LIKE '$vyraz') 
                  ORDER BY `id` desc LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more related to MySQL then CI. Maybe this will help you:

1. [Php/MySql array search with ã, š, é, ë, ú, ü, í, ž](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081087/php-mysql-array-search-with-a-s-e-e-u-u-i-z)
2. [Reading signs like č ć đ š ž from MySql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057048/reading-signs-like-c-c-d-s-z-from-mysql-database)

Comment: I have tables is UTF8_Slovak_CI